# Inserting javascript variables into escaped JSON string

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, amazon-ses

In order to pass template variables to Amazon SES, templateData needs to be in the form of a string with escaped quotes, as the following:

```
"TemplateData": "{ \"subject\": \"mySubject\", \"date\": \"myDate\", \"header\": \"myHeader\", \"message\": \"myMessage\" }"
```

I need to pass data from a firestore document into these template values. I have tried using ES6's Template strings but the string is not being accepted as valid:

```
"TemplateData": `{ \"subject\": \"${createdData.subject}\", \"date\": \"${createdData.date}\", \"header\": \"${createdData.header}\", \"message\": \"${createdData.message}\" }`
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try the old fashioned way ("string" + variable)?

Comment: Try without the backslashes

Comment: I'l try without, but Amazon's documentation, and a bunch of other guides, have them as escaped for some reason - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-personalized-email-api.html

Comment: Have you try JSON.stringify

Comment: @adiga yes, but I think in this particular case, it has to be a string literal beginning with double quotes

Comment: @ogot you can `JSON.stringify()` and object and then `JSON.stringify` the resulting string to get escaped quotes.

Comment: Do not put JSON text in string literals. Read the text from an extra file, or create the object on the fly and serialise it to JSON.

Comment: @Bergi - this is the format described in the AWS documentation.

Comment: @MarkMeyer - thanks will try!

Comment: @ogot Oh, Amazon is nesting JSON inside JSON again, a really horrible practice. You *definitely* should create that HTTP message programmatically with `JSON.stringify`, not by doing this escaping manually in string literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
const createdData = {
subject: '1',
date: '2',
header: '3',
message: '4'
}

const string = JSON.stringify(createdData)
const escapedString = JSON.stringify(string)
```

Comment: I just tried this method, and it returns the required string: "{\"subject\":\"test\"}"

However, now I am getting another error "Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value"

If I hard code the string, it works fine - so I really don't know what's wrong here.

Comment: Thanks, I just needed to include all the template variables.